# How to do a general data fetching in next.js 14 with app routing

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I am trying to do a general fetching data in a project with next.js 14 with app routing, I mean, I want to fetch data from an API service in the server side just once for all the website, not in every page.
(if someone knows nuxt.js, I want to achieve something like nuxtServerInit)

Since I am using app routing, the folder "app" is the one that contains the pages files, for example  "app/about/page.tsx", so I can not use methods like getStaticProps, getServerSideProps, getInitialProps, neither files like _app.js or _document.js. (they didn't work or they are not recommended)

¿What is the approach that I could follow to achieve it? ¿is there another method or file that I can use?

this is the basic structure of my project.

[image]

Comment: Those methods are no longer recommended in latest Nextjs version. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns